# Postgres unable to load ssl certificate

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl

I'm trying to run postgres docker container with secure connections using self generated SSL.

I created the certificates using openssl {crt,key} and mapped them inside docker container of postgres. initially the error was

```
postgres  | 2023-04-08 11:15:25.669 UTC [1] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/postgres.key" has group or world access
postgres  | 2023-04-08 11:15:25.669 UTC [1] DETAIL:  File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root.
postgres  | 2023-04-08 11:15:25.669 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

after fixing permissions I got this error for which I could not find any working solution.

```
postgres  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres  | 
postgres  | 2023-04-08 11:16:12.762 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/postgres.crt": SSL error code 2147483661
postgres  | 2023-04-08 11:16:12.769 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

certificate was created using this:

```
openssl req -x509 \
        -sha256 -days 356 \
        -nodes \
        -newkey rsa:4096 \
        -subj "/CN=$domain/C=US/L=$location" \
        -keyout $name.key \
        -out $name.crt
```

this is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine3.17
    hostname: postgre
    restart: on-failure:3
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 173.19.0.10
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=system
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgres/data
    command: postgres -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/etc/ssl/postgres.crt -c ssl_key_file=/etc/ssl/postgres.key
    volumes:
      - /var/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgres/data
      - /etc/config/certs:/etc/ssl

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 173.19.0.0/24
          gateway: 173.19.0.1
```

Comment: I think is a permission issue. Remove the command where link the certificate to the PostgreSQL, then launch the compose, attach a console, become the postgres user `sudo -i -u postgres` and check if you can read the certificate `cat /etc/ssl/postgres.crt`.

Comment: @Max I tried and I was able to view and print the contents of both files {crt, key} using cat command _cat /etc/ssl/postgres.crt_

Comment: jic, if you made crt/key files, for example, from a .pfx file using openssl, check if the versions of openssl match on the machine where you created the files and where you put them, i.e. host and container. I had a problem when generated crt/key using openssl 3.x and the container had openssl 1.x.x, when I used the same version the problem was gone

Comment: I checked, both are same, that is, _OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)_

Comment: The permissions error indicates a security feature; it's checking that your file's permissions aren't _too open_ so the server doesn't use a key that's easy for another process to steal. The fact that you can `cat` the key doesn't refute that; indeed, it supports it (if you're in fact trying to do so from any user _other than_ `postgres`; if you ran the `cat` test as the postgres user it doesn't tell us anything relevant at all).

Comment: The other error you got after fixing the permissions issue is more ambiguous, but one way to get there is for your key to be saved with DOS/Windows newlines instead of as a UNIX text file.

Comment: Either way, Stack Overflow isn't the best place for questions about service configuration -- we're narrowly focused on _writing code_. It's telling that the place the prior report on the newline issue causing a similar error code came from is [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/316907/ssl-error-unable-to-read-server-certificate-from-file), which is generally better suited to the topic.

Comment: I had checked that and NO, i do not touch windows, neither do my certificates have ^M line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

at last !!!
after wasting 6 hours on weekend, I solved the issue. Turns out it wasn't related to

1. certificate corruption
2. line terminated at ^M windows - linux issues
3. PEM file format in the cert file
4. location of the file

it turned out to be permission issue. I used

```
chmod 640 postgres.*
```

as recommended in the postgres log messages which was very incorrect. The correct permissions are

```
chmod 400 postgres.*
```

As soon as this change was made, postgres container started working just fine. Here are the logs

```
postgres  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres  | 
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.206 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.207 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.207 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.208 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.216 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-04-08 19:16:40 UTC
postgres  | 2023-04-08 19:16:40.223 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

and here is the verification by psql

```
postgre:/#  psql "dbname=system host=localhost user=root password=somepassword port=5432 sslmode=require"
psql (15.2)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I generate certificates from  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html and I did the config as you done. When I execute docker compose up after changing permission to 400 as you I got SSL error code 2147483661.